# Use of Mono flatMap causes compilation errors

Tags: java, mono, project-reactor

I am attempting to use a Reactor Mono object to process some data. I am attempting to use the FlatMap lambda in a manner that is shown in the documentation I read, but I am having some compilation problems.

The code I am using is simple test code:

```
Mono<String> astring = Mono.just("Testing some string data");

astring.flatMap(test-> {
   System.out.println("Test String: "+test);
});
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
The method flatMap<Function<? Super String> extends Mono<? extends R> in the type Mono<String> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> test) ->{}
```

I do not understand what is wrong here. I am using the exact syntax that is shown in every document I have read about using flatMap with Mono.

Am I doing something wrong here? If so, what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Mono` docs we can read that flatMap should take a function as argument:

```
flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Mono<? extends R>> transformer)
```

This function should returns `Mono`

Your function returns `void`

Comment: Man, I feel stupid. Missing a return??? Oh,well...

Answer (score 0):

`flatMap()` (and `map()`) are for *transforming* your data - you are just displaying the value, so you want to use `doOnNext()`.

Comment: You are correct about that, but the code snippet I included was more of an example/test. I intend to do transformations using the flatMap(), but I am working for a company that wants to keep the data and the transformations that I will do proprietary. I cannot put them here.